# How to trigger a JS function in HTML with multiple context.res from REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, azure-functions

I am using the following code in an HTML web page:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url= "my azure httptrigger";
request.open('GET', url, true);
request.onload = function () {

  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  var data = this.response;

  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML  = data;
function2();
  } else {
    console.log('error');
  }
}
request.send();
```

In my API (httptrigger in Azure Functions) I use:

```
context.res = {
    body: bodyStuff,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
    }
}
```

to determine the data to send back from the API. This means when I end the Azure function - the data sent in the `body` in `context.res` is sent to my webpage and displayed.

This works fine and as planned. However, what I am looking for is the ability to send data back in two parts.

(I attempted to define `context.res` twice but this didn't work as the second definition overrode the first)

Is there an effective way to do this?

In essence, a user hits my API and I want to send partial data to the web page from the API halfway through the function, and then more data at the end. This is to make the user experience on the web page quicker than waiting for all the data to load/function to finish.

Comment: This won't work. what kind of data are you sending ? list  ? independent data ?

Comment: If it's long running operation you should use durable functions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview#pattern-3-async-http-apis,
https://blog.mexia.com.au/async-http-apis-with-azure-durable-functions

Comment: @Thomas I am sending similar data, I just want it to part load some to speed up the experience for the User. I have been playing around with a search feature and want it to return some known results first before returning further results it looks for. It returns HTML.

Comment: try to google table pagination ajax, something like that, it should give you some samples

Comment: Would you mind validating my answer? @JDT

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is something that can't be done just with azure functions.

Seems like you want to divide the payload without dividing the logic, and that won't work for the HTTP protocol.

This protocol means 1 request, and 1 answer. Which means that you need to select a different protocol to make this happen.

You could have the option to use sockets, to use streamable data or other methods, but you can't append data to an HTTP request, once it has been fired.

And the azure functions are an implementation on top of HTTP, that is why the `context.res` is being overridden, because you can only answer one thing.

What you could do is to make several calls instead of a very long and big one. And try to divide the "quick" logic from the "slow" one, so that you can load elements quicker.